# Retrieve ClientId from Html.TextBoxFor in a EditorTemplates

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, editortemplates

I want to make a calendar with JQuery out of an EditorTamplates. But I am struggling with getting the id of the input text coming from Html.TextBoxFor. And as I would like to have more than one calendar onto a view, I cannot assign that value directly and have to follow the context of my control.

The view :

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="MvcContrib.FluentHtml.ModelViewUserControl<DateTimeModel>"  %>

<%= Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Date) %>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Date, new { @class="common-textbox-ui-calendar-tb"})%>

<script> 
    var CalendarTBId = '<%= this.IdFor(x=>x.Date) %>'; 
</script>
```

And the model :

```
public class DateTimeModel 
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

So far I have tried with MvContrib, but when I would have expected to get "Filter_StartDate_Date", I receive only "Date".

Have you any bright ideas to solve that?

thanks in advance,

[Edit]

I have added the following to my view :

```
<% Guid ControlGuid = Guid.NewGuid(); %>
<%= this.TextBox(x=> x.Date.ToShortDateString()).Id(ControlGuid.ToString()) %>
<script> 
    var CalendarTBId = '<%= ControlGuid  %>'; 
</script>
```

But I quite dislike it. It looks like an hack to the view to me. What do you think?

[/Edit]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this question: [get the generated clientid for a form field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418898/get-the-generated-clientid-for-a-form-field), this is my answer:

I use this helper:

```
public static partial class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString ClientIdFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)));
    }
}
```

Use it just as you would any other helper: @Html.ClientIdFor(model=>model.client.email)