# get the generated clientid for a form field

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to get the client id generated for a field generated with a html helper?

i have several components that sometimes are inside another forms, and i wan't to attach javascript events to them.

so, for sample, i would like to have:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.client.email)

<script> 
$('#@getmyusercontrolid(model=>model.client.email)').val("put your mail here");
</script>
```

Comment: The accepted answer is out of date, see my answer for a better solution.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I use this helper:

```
public static partial class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString ClientIdFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)));
    }
}
```

Use it just as you would any other helper: `@Html.ClientIdFor(model=>model.client.email)`

Comment: Sorry to mix my metaphors but this works like a well-oiled charm

Comment: Where are you getting `ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText` from?

Comment: In order to use the helper on my page I had to import the namespace where the helper is located: @import MyWebProj.Helpers. Fore more information, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239006/how-to-import-a-namespace-in-razor-view-page (it is also possible to use web.config inside the Views folder to handle the imports)

Comment: You could have just used `html.IdFor(expression)`

Comment: **Out of date as of MVC 4**, future readers—`IdFor` does this out of the box now; see [@Bonner웃's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32270976/1958726)

Answer (score 11):

MVC 5 has [NameFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833703%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), so your example using it is:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.client.email)

<script> 
$('#@Html.NameFor(model => model.client.email)').val("put your mail here");
</script>
```

**EDIT**

[IdFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833709%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) is also available, which may be more appropriate in this situation than `NameFor`.

Answer (score 9):

Use `@Html.IdFor(model => model.client.email)` as this functionality already exists like so:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.client.email)

<script> 
$('#@Html.IdFor(model => model.client.email)').val("put your mail here");
</script>
```

You can read more about it at the following page:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833709%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You could try specifying the id in the HtmlAttributes argument when you generate the input field, e.g.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.client.email, new { id = "emailTextBox" })
```

Then you can use this in your javaScript

```
var email = $('#emailTextBox').val();
```

Comment: that will not work if you have more than one instances of the component in the same page, and its also not useful if you want to databind in the destination action.

Comment: I know this is an old answer but... when using MVC and Razor view engine you need to escape the id using the `@` symbol example: `@id="emailTextBox"`