# jQuery Selector For "Html.CheckBoxFor"

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

Is there a way using asp.net/jquery to toggle a div visibility when using a checkbox like this:

`<%: Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Type) %>`

I know how to do the jQuery part, but I'm not sure how to determine whether or not the box has been clicked or changed. Is there some sort of onChange or onClick I can add to this?

**EDIT - Let me change this a bit...HOW can I assign an id to the Html.CheckBoxFor()??**

Comment: I think the id of the checkbox will be automatically set to the object property it's been created for. So in the example above it would be 'id="Type"'. You could always have a look at the mark-up your code creates to double-check.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could subscribe for the [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event and [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) the visibility of the div based on whether the checkbox has been checked or not:

```
$(function() {
    $('#mycheckbox').change(function() {
        var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
        $('#someDivId').toggle(isChecked);
    });
});
```

And you can [see it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/tdhHJ/2/).

To identify this checkbox you could either assign it an unique id:

```
<%: Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Type, new { id = "mycheckbox" }) %>
```

or a class:

```
<%: Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Type, new { @class = "check" }) %>
```

and then adapt your jQuery selector.

Comment: What I meant was how can I assign an ID to the checkbox? I am using the CheckBoxFor in ASP.Net and I am unsure how to set the id.

Comment: @Doctor Oreo, by default the Html.CheckBoxFor helper assigns an id. It will be inferred from the lambda expression in your view models object hierarchy. So if we are at level 0, it will be `id="Type"`. You could of course customize this by using the proper overload of the CheckBoxFor helper as shown in my updated answer.

Comment: For some reason, I have to check the box and uncheck it for the function() to register.

Comment: @Doctor Oreo, the change event is (as it name suggests) triggered only when the value of the checkbox changes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an onclick/onchange event for most of html element.

Let assume your checkbox has an id="checkbox1", you can do the following

```
var myCheckBox = document.getElementById("checkbox1");
myCheckBox.addEventListener('change', function(){do something}, false);
```

Comment: What I meant was how can I assign an ID to the checkbox? I am using the CheckBoxFor in ASP.Net and I am unsure how to set the id.

Answer (score 0):

See this question: [get the generated clientid for a form field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418898/get-the-generated-clientid-for-a-form-field), this is my answer:

I use this helper:

```
public static partial class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString ClientIdFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(
              htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(
                  ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)));
    }
}
```

Use it just as you would any other helper: @Html.ClientIdFor(model=>model.client.email)

or in the script:

```
$(function() {
    $('#@Html.ClientIdFor(m=>m.Type)').change(function() {
        // Do stuff
    });
});
```